# Understanding the definition of boundary points of a manifold

Tags: manifolds-with-boundary

Let $M$ be a topological manifold. We call it a $n$-manifold with boundary if for each $x\in M$, there is a chart $(U,\phi)$ at $x$ such that $\phi$ is a homeomorphism from $U$ to an open subset of $\mathbb{H}^n$, where $\mathbb{H}^n=\{(x_1,x_2,\cdots, x_n): x_n\ge 0\}$. Define $x\in M$ to be a boundary point if $\phi(x)\in\partial\mathbb{H}^n$ for some chart $(U,\phi)$ at $x$. How can I show that this definition does not depend on the choice of the chart?

Comment: I think you need some homology theory to prove this. The idea is given in  the answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1269687/boundary-of-a-topological-manifold-invariant.